# Nested attributes in mongodb confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise, mongoid

I am using rails with database Mongodb.
I am using devise . Devise has model name user.The id of the user is in

```
:id => current_user.id
```

I want to make a model such that when data is save from the form the id of the current user will also save in the collection.
The model of my employee is

```
 class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :first_name, type: String
  field :middle_name, type: String
  field :last_name, type: String
  field :otherid, type: String
  field :licennum, type: String
  field :citizennum, type: String
  field :licenexp, type: String
  field :gender, type: String
   field :state, type: String
  field :marital_status, type: String
  field :country, type: String
  field :birthdate, type: String
  field :nickname, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  validates_presence_of :first_name
```

{
}

```
end
```

what should i put inside curly bracket so that when data is saved from that model it saves the current user id also inside it?

Answer (score 1):

The code you show only contains personal information fields like birth date and such. I suppose the simplest solution would be to place them inside the `User` class, and change them using built-in devise actions such as `devise/registrations#edit`, which applies the changes to `current_user` as default.

Alternatively, if you want to keep Employee as a separate class, you could try embedding `Employee` in `User` class, like this:

```
class User 
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_one :employee
  (...)

class Employee
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user
```

In this case, you would set up the relation at controller level, e.g.:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    current_user.create_employee(params[:employee])
  end
```

After creation, you could access the user's ID from Employee class as `user.id`.